# Instantiate a class in a case-insensitive way

Tags: php, oop

I'm faced with a bit of an issue. I have my class name in a variable and I need to instantiate it, but I have no way of knowing that my variable has the exact same case than the class.

Example:

```
//The class I'm fetching is named "App_Utils_MyClass"
$var = "myclass";
$className = "App_Utils_".$var;
$obj = new $className();
```

How can I make this work?

Additional info:

- I have a `class_exists()` check (case insensitive) before this snippet to make sure that the class I want actually exists.
- The class name is always properly camel-cased (e.g. `MySuperAwesomeClass`).

Comment: I use class_exists (which is case insensitive) to check that the class actually exists

Comment: Just like the spelling should be correct, the case should also be correct. How can it be that you expect the spelling to be correct but the casing to maybe not be correct?

Comment: @Squ36 , aah. so class_exists() gives true, but if the casing is wrong, the instantiation could go wrong. Is that your problem?

Comment: @nl-x : the variable $var is from a user input. I can't expect the user to respect the case every time

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Contrary to the popular belief, function names in PHP are not case-sensitive, same for a class constructor. Your `case` should already work. Try this

```
<?php
class TestClass {
    var $testValue; 
}


$a=new testclass();
$b=new TestClass();
$c=new TESTCLASS();
print_r($a);
print_r($b);
print_r($c);

?>
```

According to [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php)

> Note:  Function names are case-insensitive, though it is usually good form to call functions as they appear in their declaration.

This applies to your class methods aswell.

**Workaround/Better way to Name those Classes**

The following will ensure that the class name will always be in the exact case as was defined by you, doesn't matter in which `case` user enters it

```
<?php       
class TestClass {
    var $testValue; 
}


$userEnteredValue="testCLASS";
$myClasses=get_declared_classes();
$classNameIndex=array_search(strtolower($userEnteredValue), array_map('strtolower', $myClasses));
if($classNameIndex!==FALSE)
{
    $classNameShouldBe=$myClasses[$classNameIndex];
      echo $classNameShouldBe;
}
else
{
    echo "This class is undefined";
}




?>
```

Comment: Hi. I just saw that! I was convinced that the class and method names were case sensitive. Thanks for the info

Comment: I really dislike that feature in this language, it allows room for bad coding practices but then there are many more things to cry about. Using names like that is not advisable but that unfortunately is the answer to your question

Comment: Yeah I know. I like clean code and this forces me to go against my beliefs, but I don't have a choice...

Comment: In fact you do, you can make a lookup table or whitelist and then use proper names from it once you have a match

Comment: I could, but the database I'm working on is already crowded, and maintaining a whitelist is a pain. Especially since the list of class I can instantiate with this could be rapidly growing...

Comment: Mmmmmmm this is interesting, wait let me write up something for it :)

Comment: Thanks ! This is actually a really clever way. I'll use it now, and store it somewhere else, may be of use some day ;)

Comment: Be careful, HHVM is case sensitive. If you want to be compatible with it, you will have to ensure the cases match.